# Xposed module to disable 'connected to WiFi network whatever'

Tags: android, wifi

My WiFi connection drops and reconnects frequently. On each reconnect, it pops up a message stating "connected to WiFi network {SSID}", which is quite annoying.

Is there an Xposed module that will disable that notification?

Comment: [NotifyClean](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.defim.apk.notifyclean)?

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't seem to pick up this notification. This notification occurs at the bottom of the screen, not in the top bar. It's not one of the ones listed in notifyclean under phone, system ui or android system :/

Comment: Are you sure it is a notification and not a toast? If a toast, have you tried [EnhancedToast](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.defim.apk.enhancedtoast)? Perhaps a screenshot would do good here.

Comment: For some background on what @Firelord is asking, please see [Popups, dialogs, notifications, toasts: what's the difference?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/52789/16575) on our Android sister site.

Comment: My mistake, it was a toast. That module suggested killed it, thanks.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2449683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message is displayed as a [Toast](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html). The solution is the Xposed module [EnhancedToast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.defim.apk.enhancedtoast) which can hide any toast it had recorded so far since it was installed. You have to install it → enable its module under Xposed Installer app followed by reboot → launch it → select your app<sup><sup>2</sup></sup> → select the toast to hide it. Selecting an entry would turn its background color to red.

**Note**: an Xposed module requires a compatible<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> Xposed framework installed.

Example:

<sub>(Click an image to enlarge it)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

---

<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> <sub>Xposed Framework:  [Android 4.x, 5.x and 6.x](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811)</sub>
<sup><sup>2</sup></sup> <sub>My take is that either it is Android System or Settings or SystemUI responsible for creating that toast.</sub>

Comment: 'Settings' is responsible for the toast. If you disable toasts from that app, you might not see important messages/errors.